# primep function in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, primes

I am new to common lisp. I wrote the following predicate function implementing the *trial-division* algorithm. Is there still a shorter and lispier way of writing this? Any helps or suggestions are appreciated.

```
(defun primep (n)
  "trial-division"
  (case (find 0 (loop for i upfrom 2 upto (expt n 1/2) collect (mod n i)))
    (0 nil)
    (otherwise t)))


(mapcar (lambda (n) (list n (primep n)))
        (loop for i upto 100 collect i))


=> ((0 T) (1 T) (2 T) (3 T) (4 NIL) (5 T) (6 NIL) (7 T) (8 NIL) (9 NIL) (10 NIL)
 (11 T) (12 NIL) (13 T) (14 NIL) (15 NIL) (16 NIL) (17 T) (18 NIL) (19 T)
 (20 NIL) (21 NIL) (22 NIL) (23 T) (24 NIL) (25 NIL) (26 NIL) (27 NIL) (28 NIL)
 (29 T) (30 NIL) (31 T) (32 NIL) (33 NIL) (34 NIL) (35 NIL) (36 NIL) (37 T)
 (38 NIL) (39 NIL) (40 NIL) (41 T) (42 NIL) (43 T) (44 NIL) (45 NIL) (46 NIL)
 (47 T) (48 NIL) (49 NIL) (50 NIL) (51 NIL) (52 NIL) (53 T) (54 NIL) (55 NIL)
 (56 NIL) (57 NIL) (58 NIL) (59 T) (60 NIL) (61 T) (62 NIL) (63 NIL) (64 NIL)
 (65 NIL) (66 NIL) (67 T) (68 NIL) (69 NIL) (70 NIL) (71 T) (72 NIL) (73 T)
 (74 NIL) (75 NIL) (76 NIL) (77 NIL) (78 NIL) (79 T) (80 NIL) (81 NIL) (82 NIL)
 (83 T) (84 NIL) (85 NIL) (86 NIL) (87 NIL) (88 NIL) (89 T) (90 NIL) (91 NIL)
 (92 NIL) (93 NIL) (94 NIL) (95 NIL) (96 NIL) (97 T) (98 NIL) (99 NIL)
 (100 NIL))
```

Comment: `LOOP` has a `NEVER`-clause for checking that a condition is never true. e.g. `(loop ... never (zerop (mod n i)))`

Comment: wow! very nice thank you

Comment: @jkiiski Do you know of any good source for learning about `loop`?

Comment: Try the [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), for `LOOP`, see chapter [22. LOOP for Black Belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html).

Answer (score 3):

See [`*primes*`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/cllib/math.lisp#l182) and friends in [CLOCC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clocc/)/CLLIB.

Note that 0 and 1 are *not* primes.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#Common_Lisp

```
(defun primep (n)
  "Is N prime?"
  (and (> n 1) 
       (or (= n 2) (oddp n))
       (loop for i from 3 to (isqrt n) by 2
             never (zerop (rem n i)))))
```